# Panel won't fire "added" or "removed", when adding or removing items

Tags: events, panel, sencha-touch

This is my panel (Take notice of the listeners):

```
ToolbarDemo.views.homecard = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, 
{
    title: "Meny",
    iconCls: "home",
    scroll: "vertical",
    tpl: [
        '<tpl for=".">',
        '   <div class="x-component" style="height: 110px">',
        '       <div class="home_button_container">',
        '           <img class="home_button" src="{url_icon_large}" />',
        '           <p class="home_button_text">{name}</p>',
        '       </div>',
    '       </div>',
        '</tpl>'
    ], 
    bodyStyle: "background-color: #FFFFFF !important; background-image: url(images/background.png) !important; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:bottom left;",
    initComponent: function() 
    {
        Ext.apply(this, 
        {
            dockedItems: [{
                xtype: "toolbar"
            }],
            defaults: {height: "110px"},
            items: [
                componentArray
            ]
        }); 

        this.addListener("added", function()
        {
            console.log("Somthing has been added");
            this.doLayout();
        })

        this.addListener("render", function()
        {
            makeJSONPRequest();
            console.log("Finished rendering");
            this.doLayout();
        })

        this.addListener("removed", function()
        {
            console.log("Somthing has been removed");
            this.doLayout();
        })
            //item(fronterButton);
        ToolbarDemo.views.homecard.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    }

});
```

When i do a remove all

```
ToolbarDemo.views.homecard.removeAll();
```

Nothing happens. Nothing fires. Nada.

i've even tried removeAll through the console, but nothing fires.

Does anyone have a clue what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're listening to the wrong events.

If you want to listen for items being added/removed on a container, you want add/remove.

If you want to listen for a component being added/removed from a container, you want added/removed.